# Unwind a list in mongodb and filter on it

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of date objects for each document. I would like to return a list of documents that fit a date range corresponding to the date range. So I need to use the unwind, to unwind each of the dates in the list and then compare them. However I am having issues making this work.

```
pipeline = [{"$unwind": "$date_object"}, 
            {"date_object": {"$lte": future, "$gte": today}}, 
            ] 

courses = mongo.db.coll.aggregate(pipeline)
```

When I try this I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'date_object'
```

How should I format the pipeline/query?

Comment: I think the reason you're getting this error message is because you're missing the `$match` operator. `{ '$match': { 'date_object': { '$lte': future, '$gte': today } } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it with `$match`

```
pipeline = [{"$unwind": "$date_object"}, 
            {$match: {"date_object": {"$lte": future, "$gte": today}}}]; 

courses = mongo.db.coll.aggregate(pipeline)
```